# How to solve a connection error within ros_azure_iothub from ROS to Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: azure, ros, azure-iot-hub

We are trying to establish a connection between ROS System and the Azure IoT Hub. We have IoT Devices connected to the AzureIoTHub. We want to get the Information from the IoT Devices within our ROS System, this is why we need the Node.

We are using ROS Melodic on Windows.
We are using the following repository: https://github.com/microsoft/ros_azure_iothub
We did the stuff explained in the link and tried the : Deployment (Client side) chapter...

We get the following error in ROS, while we are trying to connect with our AzureIoT Hub:

> INFO] [1694792380.948178700]: Creating IoTHub Device handle[ INFO] [1694792380.951205800]: connection_string: SetAnonymusByMyself [ INFO] [1694792380.952589500]: Using Shared Access Signatures authentication. Error: Time:Fri Sep 15 17:40:02 2023 File:D:\bld\azure-c-shared-utility\src\305becb8b4-13d51db0dd.clean\adapters\socketio_win32.c Func:connect_socket Line:190 Failure: connect failure 10060. Error: Time:Fri Sep 15 17:40:02 2023 File:D:\bld\azure-c-shared-utility\src\305becb8b4-13d51db0dd.clean\adapters\socketio_win32.c Func:initiate_socket_connection Line:228 connect_socket failed Error: Time:Fri Sep 15 17:40:02 2023 File:D:\bld\azure-c-shared-utility\src\305becb8b4-13d51db0dd.clean\adapters\socketio_win32.c Func:socketio_open Line:475 initiate_socket_connection failed Error: Time:Fri Sep 15 17:40:02 2023 File:D:\bld\azure-umqtt-c\src\6589726cd0-9f313f3693.clean\src\mqtt_client.c Func:onOpenComplete Line:454 Error: failure opening connection to endpoint Error: Time:Fri Sep 15 17:40:02 2023 File:D:\bld\azure-c-shared-utility\src\305becb8b4-13d51db0dd.clean\adapters\tlsio_schannel.c Func:tlsio_schannel_open Line:1238 xio_open failed Error: Time:Fri Sep 15 17:40:02 2023 File:D:\bld\azure-umqtt-c\src\6589726cd0-9f313f3693.clean\src\mqtt_client.c Func:mqtt_client_connect Line:1042 Error: io_open failed Error: Time:Fri Sep 15 17:40:02 2023 File:D:\bld\azure-iot-sdk-c\src\22e1b375fe-0b7b930b40.clean\iothub_client\src\iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func:SendMqttConnectMsg Line:2329 failure connecting to address facpremiumhub.azure-devices.net. [ INFO] [1694792402.066324300]: The device client has been disconnected`

Within /rosout, we receive the following message:

> \header:
> seq: 87
> stamp:
> secs: 1694791855
> nsecs: 961817300
> frame_id: ''
> level: 2
> name: "/roscpp_azure_iothub_node"
> msg: "The device client has been disconnected"
> file: "C:\catkin_ws\src\ros_azure_iothub\roscpp_azure_iothub\src\ros_azure_iothub_cpp_node.cpp"
> function: "__cdecl connection_status_callback"
> line: 163
> topics:
>
> /rosout

I already changed the connection string to something completly random and afterwards, the connection error is something completly different. So I assume, that the connection string is correct. Could there be any problem, with some network settings?

Does anyone have an idea, where does that come from or what could be the issue?
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Kindly regards

Comment: could you please the reference you used for Ros to azure IoT Hub

Comment: Hello, sorry but what do you mean with reference?

Comment: any DOC or links you followed

Comment: Ah sorry... https://github.com/microsoft/ros_azure_iothub
We did the stuff explained in the link and tried the : Deployment (Client side) chapter...

Comment: It is connecting fine for me it might be a networking issue/troubleshoot  check the logs

Comment: sorry for the stupid questions, but I am a complete newbie... could you provide a path where I find the logs?

Comment: in your output I can see [INFO] they are the sample information logs, by seeing them We can tell `Incorrect Connection String`/`Connectivity Issue`